# How to filter out data on the basis of empId then projId in array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects which is having individual task and I need to filter out the each task according to employee id and then project id and after this I need to check if the sum of hours in the resulting array is less than 4.
If all these conditions satisfy then store those values in the array.
This is the response from api.

```
nonallocated: [
  {
    empId: "1",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "111"
      },
      total: '2'
    }
  },
  {
    empId: "2",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "111"
      },
      total: '5'
    }
  },
{
    empId: "2",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "333"
      },
      total: '1'
    }
  },
  {
    empId: "3",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "111"
      },
      total: '2'
    }
  },
  {
    empId: "3",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "111"
      },
      total: '1'
    }
  },
  {
    empId: "1",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "222"
      },
      total: '5'
    }
  },
  {
    empId: "1",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "111"
      },
      total: '1'
    }
  }
]
```

expected output:

```
newArr = [
  //matching empId(1), projectId(111), total is less than 4 i.e 2+1=3
  {
   empId: "1",
   task: {
    project: {
      projectId: "111"
   },
   total: '2'
  }
 },
{
   empId: "1",
   task: {
    project: {
      projectId: "111"
   },
   total: '1'
  }
 },
// having only one data for same empID and projectId and total is less than 4
{
  empId: "2",
  task: {
    project: {
      projectId: "333"
    },
    total: '1'
  }
 },
//having same empId(3) and projectId(111) and total is less than 4 ie 
  2+1 =3
{
empId: "3",
task: {
  project: {
    projectId: "111"
  },
  total: '2'
}
},
{
  empId: "3",
  task: {
    project: {
      projectId: "111"
    },
    total: '1'
   }
  },
 ]
```

this should not be limited to one empId or projectId. I want these conditions to satisfy on any data for example we can have a data which has same conditions satisfied for empId 2.
I want to retrieve the data for values which have same employee Id, same projectId and total less than 4. and if I have a data which doesn't have empId and projectId matched with other data just check the total less than 4 in that case

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: I want a array with same form satisfying all the above conditions @Layhout

Comment: give me a dummy unfiltered data and your expected result from that dummy data.

Comment: if the code snippet above is the result you expected, then what does the original unfiltered data look like?

Comment: I have edited the post for expected output @Layhout

Comment: so you looking for employee id 1 and project id 111?

Comment: and their total should be less than 4 @Layhout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const nonallocated = [
    {
        empId: "1",
        task: {
            project: {
                projectId: "111"
            },
            total: '2'
        }
    },
    {
        empId: "2",
        task: {
            project: {
                projectId: "111"
            },
            total: '5'
        }
    },
    {
        empId: "2",
        task: {
            project: {
                projectId: "333"
            },
            total: '1'
        }
    },
    {
        empId: "3",
        task: {
            project: {
                projectId: "111"
            },
            total: '2'
        }
    },
    {
        empId: "3",
        task: {
            project: {
                projectId: "111"
            },
            total: '1'
        }
    },
    {
        empId: "1",
        task: {
            project: {
                projectId: "222"
            },
            total: '5'
        }
    },
    {
        empId: "1",
        task: {
            project: {
                projectId: "111"
            },
            total: '1'
        }
    }
]

const filterGroup = capTotal => {
    return nonallocated.filter(n => {
        const sumTotal = nonallocated.reduce((p, c) => {
            if (c.empId === n.empId && c.task.project.projectId === n.task.project.projectId)
                p += Number(c.task.total);
            return p;
        }, 0);
        return sumTotal < capTotal;
    })
}

const newArr = filterGroup(4);

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: You have passed arguments in filterArr() as hardcoded value. But this value should filtered on the basis of values in response.

Comment: How can we get it dynamically for example if we had data for empId - 2 having all conditions satisfied? i.e same empId projectId and total less than 3

Comment: I have edited the data and expected output. Can you plz help with solution according to that

Comment: *"this value should filtered on the basis of values in response"*, so? just pass the values from the response to the function and you will get the result.

Comment: in your latest edited expected output, all of those data have in common is their total is less than four. so empId and projectId don't matter and their total is all you care about?

Comment: and what is `2+1=3`? where it come from?

Comment: 2+1 is the sum of totals of  two tasks having same empId and projectId, which I have written below that comment

Comment: i start to understand now. what if there's another data that has empId 1, projectId 111 and total 3? will it be in the newArr?

Comment: No, then the total will be 2+1+3= 6, which is not according to the condition i.e total should be less than 4

Comment: @user20042604 i edited my answer and it passed the test case.

Comment: @user20042604 please click accept my answer.

Comment: ok I have accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this - just use filter on the array and make a match on what you want to match on:

```js
const nonallocate = [
  {
    empId: "1",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "111"
      },
      total: '2'
    }
  },
  {
    empId: "2",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "111"
      },
      total: '3'
    }
  },
  {
    empId: "1",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "222"
      },
      total: '1'
    }
  },
  {
    empId: "1",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "111"
      },
      total: '1'
    }
  }
]

const result = nonallocate.filter(item => {
  const total = item?.task?.total || 0
  return item.empId === '1' && parseInt(total, 10) <= 4
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: And how can I do this for if I have had the data with all conditions satified for empId 2. here you are using item.empId === '1'

Comment: Change it to what you want

Comment: can you plz look ka the example response and expected output. I have edited the question

Comment: @user20042604 Your question is not making sense. Use the examples to write your own filter. This isn't a free site for code, but a guide to help you figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Posting my approach:

```
var proj="111";
var empl="1";
var filtered=nonallocated.filter(e => e.empId===empl && e.task && e.task.project && e.task.project.projectId===proj && e.task.total>0);
var tasks=filtered.map(e => parseInt(e.task.total, 10));
var total = tasks.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered))
console.log(JSON.stringify(tasks))
console.log(total);
```

Comment: this is also for hardcoded value right? But I want matching data for all EmpId and projectId which are satisfying these conditions i.e same empId, ProjectId, total less than 4

Comment: Your request is not clear. Above you said "Q: so you looking for employee id 1 and project id 111? --> A: and their total should be less than 4 ". That's what this solution is proposing. Or do you want to retrieve all employee/project for which the total is <4 ?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear requirement. I want to retrieve the data for values which have same employee Id, same projectId and total less than 4. and if I have only one data which doesn't have empId and projectId matched just check the total less than 4 in that case

Comment: "I have only one data which doesn't have empId and projectId matched " : Still don't get this one. Could update your request with the different use cases you have in mind ? User Case (1) - data - expected result, Use Case (2) data - expected result, ...

Comment: I have edited the expected output and response data. Can you check now?